# change attributes data type in database table when it is already filled with records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Could we change attribute's data type when the database table has record in SQL?

I am using Microsoft Management Studio 2008. The error that i am getting is: 
** Error converting data type nvarchar to float. **

Comment: Change table column data type? if so what data type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In short:** It is possible with `alter column` command **ONLY if the altered data type is compatible** with newly modified one. In addition, it is recommended to be done with  transaction.

For example: You may change a column from a varchar(50) to a nvarchar(200), with a script below.

```
alter table TableName 
alter column ColumnName nvarchar(200)
```

**Edit:** Regarding your posted error while altering column type.

> ** Error converting data type nvarchar to float. **

One way would be to create a new column, and convert all good (*convertible and compatible*) records to new column. After that you may wanna to clean-up the bad records that do not convert, delete old column and re-name your newly added and populated column back to the original name. **Important:** use testing environment for all this manipulations first. Usually, playing with productions tables turns to be a bad practice to screw things up.

**References** to look for more discussions on similar SE posts:

- [Change column types in a huge table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10754665/1437962)
- [How to change column datatype in SQL Server database without losing data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5136013/1437962)

Comment: it is not possible by this way. The error message is, **Error converting data type nvarchar to float.**

Comment: Read my answer carefully again, i said that if data types are compatible. Of course it will not work if you try alter type double to become int.

Comment: Added a suggestion what to do when having conversion error. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, there is no default conversion to your new datatype. One solution could be to create a second column with the requested type, and write your own conversion function. Once this done, delete the first column and rename the second one with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Things to consider: How big your table is. You then use the `alter table` syntax. We do not know what data type you want to change, so just for e.g.

alter column:

```
Alter Table [yourTable] Alter column [yourColumn] varchar(15)
```

- You could also try to add a new column and then update that column using your old column. Drop the old column. Rename the new column. **This is a safe better way**, becasue at times the data that you hold might not react well to the new data type...

A post to look into for ideas: [Change column types in a huge table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754665/change-column-types-in-a-huge-table?lq=1), [How to change column datatype in SQL database without losing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136013/how-to-change-column-datatype-in-sql-server-database-without-losing-data)

Answer (score 0):

Alter datatype of that column ..But In general sql wont allow to channge.It will prompt u drop that column..There is setting to achive that thing.
Go to Tool->Option->designers->Table and Database designers and Uncheck Prevent saving option.I m taking abt sql server 2008R2.Now u can easily alter data type.[image]