# Changing an huge table column type Long to Clob

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Background: 
I want to change a table column from Long to Clob.

- I am not allowed to create/alter tablespaces
- The table has 10M + rows

What i have tried:

1. Simply alter table from long to clob:

   - returns full tablespace error - `ORA-01652`: `"unable to extend temp segment by %s in tablespace %s"`

     ---
2. Export data from table and insert in a new table:

   - export just takes too long, at the speed its going now, it will take weeks to export.

     ---
3. Running `"insert  /*+ APPEND */ into new_table select * from old_table;"`

   - returns an error -  `ORA-00997: "illegal use of LONG datatype"`

Comment: Did you try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10754753/2083907

Comment: Ask your DBA to temporally increase size of TEMP tablespace. It should be no problem I from my point of view.

Comment: @Wernfried he refused

Comment: @mbroshi, thanks for the link, gonna try that

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative. (Always test in preproduction before)

- Create a [function](http://ellebaek.wordpress.com/2010/12/06/converting-a-long-column-to-a-clob-on-the-fly/) that casts long to clob.
- Then try your third option using the function:

  insert  /*+ APPEND */ into new_table select id, long_to_clob(myLob) as myclob from old_table;
- Drop the long field.
- Add a new clob field.
- Update the new field.

  UPDATE old_table o
    SET new_field =( SELECT myclob FROM newTable n WHERE n.id = o.id)
  WHERE 1=1;