# EF Code First - Change column max length without maxing out DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework, attributes, azure-sql-database

I am dealing with a problem that most of our columns were created with default EF behaviour which makes string as nvarchar(max). However that doesn't combine well with indexes.

I tried the putting the `[MaxLength(100)]` attribute onto the specific column and generate a migration. That generates the alter table statement that when run on a database (with a lot of data) spikes the DTU and basically trashes the DB.

I am now looking for a safe way how to proceed with this (let's say that the column name is "FileName"):

1. Create a column **FileNameV2** with `[MaxLength(100)]`.
2. Copy data from **FileName** column to **FileNameV2**.
3. Delete **FileName** column.
4. Rename **FileNameV2** to **FileName**

Would this approach work or is there any better / easier way (especially one that doesn't upset EF)?

Comment: I find this interesting "*spikes the DTU and basically trashes the DB*" how does it trash it?

Comment: I reckon the alter statement results in quite a large transaction log and not sure how this works in the background - but I saw quite a big growth of the database size when this was proceeding and after a while I had to kill it (also maxed out our database size on Azure - which might be the reason of the trashing :) however I am not 100% sure)

Comment: Some other discussion; https://sqlstudies.com/2016/07/14/altering-a-column-in-a-large-table-a-case-study/

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754665/change-column-types-in-a-huge-table/10754753#10754753

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue I found out later was that our SQL Azure database had **max size** 2 GB so when I was doing the change and the db had 1,5 GB it then reached its size probably when doing the transition from **navarchar(max) to nvarchar(100)**. So the learning is to double check your max size of DB on Azure just to be sure you don't hit this threshold.